# How to set the mongodb connection string URI readonly？

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Want to use readonly mongodb Connection String URI，How can I set it?what should I add on the string uri?

I have tried add readOnly=true on options like below，but it is invalid.

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?readOnly=true&readPreference=secondary]]
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to give read/only access to the database?

Comment: thats not how do that, you need to create roles on the database where you can separe access type (read only, read/write and/or write only).

Comment: yes，I want to readonly access to the database.